# My ASP.NET server does not work and I am wondering what's missing, when I open Swagger, I get error 500

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, swagger

First of all here is my code - my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DataBase.Data;
using DataBase.Data.Models;

namespace DataBase.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FoodDatabasesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly FoodDbContext _context;

        public FoodDatabasesController(FoodDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/FoodDatabases
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<FoodDatabase>>> GetFoodDatabases()
        {
            return await _context.FoodDatabases.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/FoodDatabases/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<FoodDatabase>> GetFoodDatabase(int id)
        {
            var foodDatabase = await _context.FoodDatabases.FindAsync(id);

            if (foodDatabase == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return foodDatabase;
        }

        // PUT: api/FoodDatabases/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutFoodDatabase(int id, FoodDatabase foodDatabase)
        {
            if (id != foodDatabase.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(foodDatabase).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!FoodDatabaseExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/FoodDatabases
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<FoodDatabase>> PostFoodDatabase(FoodDatabase foodDatabase)
        {
            _context.FoodDatabases.Add(foodDatabase);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetFoodDatabase", new { id = foodDatabase.Id }, foodDatabase);
        }

        // DELETE: api/FoodDatabases/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteFoodDatabase(int id)
        {
            var foodDatabase = await _context.FoodDatabases.FindAsync(id);
            if (foodDatabase == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.FoodDatabases.Remove(foodDatabase);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool FoodDatabaseExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.FoodDatabases.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my database entity and `DbContext`:

```
public class FoodDatabase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150), Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string Food { get; set; } = "Food Name";

    [MaxLength(150), Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(300)")]
    public string Description { get; set; } = "Description";
}
```

```
public class FoodDbContext : DbContext
{
     public FoodDbContext(DbContextOptions<FoodDbContext> options)
         : base(options)
     {
     }

     public DbSet<FoodDatabase> FoodDatabases { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         // Seed data
         modelBuilder.Entity<FoodDatabase>().HasData(
             new FoodDatabase
             {
                 Id = 1,
                 Food = "Foodbread",
                 Description = "A delicious bread made for food lovers"
             });
     }
}
```

These are my 2 migrations:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace DataBase.Migrations
{
    public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "FoodDatabases",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Food = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(150)", maxLength: 150, nullable: false),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(300)", maxLength: 150, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_FoodDatabases", x => x.Id);
                });

            // Seed data
            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "FoodDatabases",
                columns: new[] { "Id", "Food", "Description" },
                values: new object[] { 1, "Foodbread", "A delicious bread made for food lovers" });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "FoodDatabases");
        }
    }
}
```

```
// <auto-generated />
using DataBase.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

#nullable disable

namespace DataBase.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(FoodDbContext))]
    partial class FoodDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "8.0.3")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

            SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity("DataBase.Data.Models.FoodDatabase", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(150)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(300)");

                    b.Property<string>("Food")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(150)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(150)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("FoodDatabases");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly here is `program.cs` and the app settings with the connection string:

```
using DataBase.Data;
using DataBase.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FoodDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

// Configure CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyOrigin();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting(); // <- This is required for routing

app.UseCors("CORSPolicy"); // Apply CORS policy

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database = WebApiReact,Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False"
  }
}
```

The problem I'm currently facing is that when I open the solution in Swagger, and I want to try out the get, post and put functions, they always throws the same error. I'm confused as to why this happens, and looking for some guidance on where I can improve it.

Here is the error I get in Swagger when I try to execute my put function:

> Error: response status is 500
>
> Response body
>
> System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. See https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode for more information. (Parameter 'name')
>
> en-us is an invalid culture identifier.
>
> at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.InternalOpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at DataBase.Controllers.FoodDatabasesController.PutFoodDatabase(Int32 id, FoodDatabase foodDatabase) in C:\Users\huday\Documents\DataBase\DataBase\Controllers\FoodDatabasesController.cs:line 59
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**HEADERS**

```
Accept: */*  
Host: localhost:7181  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br  
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5  
Content-Type: application/json  
Origin: https://localhost:7181  
Referer: https://localhost:7181/swagger/index.html
TE: trailers
Content-Length: 60
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when *opening* the Swagger page?  Or is this error the result of *invoking* the API from the Swagger page?

Comment: You should attach the error you're getting in the backend. your connection string looks a bit fishy to me though

Comment: sorry for not including the error, i can open the swagger page but i cannot execute(try it out) my put function, i have included it in the text now

Comment: Is the web app deployed in a Docker container (or a Dev Container in VS Code)? If the project file has `<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>` in it have you tried setting it to `false`?

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message?

Comment: does anybody here know where to go to learn how to connect my web api to docker

Answer (score 0):

Change your project invariant globalization settins to false. Dotnet using invariant culture by default. If you want to use specific (en-us on your sample) You should do;

Add your csproj file:

**Project.csproj**

```
<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
```

or define environment variable:

**Environment Variable**

```
DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT : false
```

or add env to your docker file:

**DockerFile**

```
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
```

Also be aware culture string should "en-US" and you can check the [other supported culture strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/supported-culture-codes)